# onActivityResult returns null

Tags: java, android

Activity 1:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText editOrt;
private EditText editPLZ;
private EditText editStrasse;
final int REQUEST_CODE = 111;
String adressdaten = "";
TextView abrufenn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editOrt = findViewById(R.id.editOrt);
    editPLZ = findViewById(R.id.editPLZ);
    editStrasse = findViewById(R.id.editStrasse);
}

public void startSecond(View view) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    String inputOrt = editOrt.getText().toString();
    String inputPLZ = editPLZ.getText().toString();
    String inputStrasse = editStrasse.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra("Ort", inputOrt);
    i.putExtra("PLZ", inputPLZ);
    i.putExtra("Strasse", inputStrasse);

    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle b = data.getExtras();

            String backStrasse    = (String) b.get("strasseback");
            String backPLZ        = (String) b.get("plzback");
            String backOrt        = (String) b.get("ortback");
            adressdaten = " " + backStrasse + " " + backPLZ + " " + backOrt;
        }
    }
}

public void abrufen (View view) {
    abrufenn = findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    abrufenn.setText(adressdaten);
}
```

}

Activity 2:

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText editOrt2;
private EditText editPLZ2;
private EditText editStrasse2;
String ort, plz, strasse;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    editOrt2 = findViewById(R.id.editOrt2);
    editPLZ2 = findViewById(R.id.editPLZ2);
    editStrasse2 = findViewById(R.id.editStrasse2);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle daten = intent.getExtras();

    String ort = (String) daten.get("Ort");
    String plz = (String) daten.get("PLZ");
    String strasse = (String) daten.get("Strasse");

    editOrt2.setText(ort);
    editPLZ2.setText(plz);
    editStrasse2.setText(strasse);

}

public void back(View view) {
    Intent result = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
    result.putExtra("strasseback", strasse);
    result.putExtra("plzback", plz);
    result.putExtra("ortback", ort);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);

    finish();

}
```

}

The Problem is that the Button "abrufenn" in method "abrufen" only shows "null null null". i dont know why but, the data does not transfer from activity 2 to activity 1, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: you say that `onActivityResult` returns `null` but specifcally what is `null` there?

Comment: `Intent result = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);`. That should be `Intent result = new Intent();`.

Comment: `onActivityResult returns null`. Nonsense. It is a void function which does return nothing. It is pretty strange that you did not explain which problem you have. Nor is there a question.

Comment: You have 4 answers already and people are asking you to provide more details in the comments section. I think you should try the solutions and comment whether they helped or not instead of creating the same question to attract more answers. If you comment under the answers and report whether they helped and if there are any errors then people can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to put it equal to bundle.
try using --
 String backStrasse = data.getStringExtra("strasseback"); 
If issue still not resolved use debugger or upload your xml files too to have better look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

change your code with this code

```
public void back(View view) {
    Intent result = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    Bundle resultBundle = new Bundle();
    resultBundle.putString("strasseback", strasse);
    resultBundle.putString("plzback", plz);
    resultBundle.putString("ortback", ort);
    result.putExtras(resultBundle);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);

    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code:

- When setting the `Intent` to `setResult`. Create it by `Intent intent = new Intent()` is enough.
- You call `result.putExtra("strasseback", strasse);`, then you have to extract it by `data.getStringExtra` or `data.getIntExtra` base on the param type, not `data.getExtras`.

Answer (score 0):

Activity 2 is ok

Activity 1 i use those Code

receive data

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if ((requestCode == 1) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)) {
        editText.setText(data.getStringExtra("result"));
    }
}
```

create forresult

```
    public void chooseDirectoryFilesClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChooseDirectoryActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```